# Getting Html from server using urllib

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to get data from a website which has a form. Now i am using urllib for this purpose. Form has three fields and thus i need to provide these three values. But what i am getting is in response is empty form's code while i am expecting a table corresponding to my input values-
here is my code snippet

```
data=urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data=data.encode('ascii')
req=urllib.request.Request(url,data,headers)
response=urllib.request.urlopen(req)
the_page=response.read()
```

Values are the input values given to the form. What i am doing wrong? Though i am not sending session id.

Comment: You have to find whether the values should be passed as `GET` or `POST` method before making the call.

Comment: Values are being sent as POST.

Comment: No first argument must be url. This is raising error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this from
http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/

```
import re   
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("http://www.example.com/")
 # follow second link with element text matching regular expression
response1 = br.follow_link(text_regex=r"cheese\s*shop", nr=1)
assert br.viewing_html()
print br.title()
print response1.geturl()
print response1.info()  # headers
print response1.read()  # body

br.select_form(name="order")
# Browser passes through unknown attributes (including methods)
# to the selected HTMLForm.
br["cheeses"] = ["mozzarella", "caerphilly"]  # (the method here is __setitem__)
# Submit current form.  Browser calls .close() on the current response on
# navigation, so this closes response1
response2 = br.submit()

# print currently selected form (don't call .submit() on this, use br.submit())
print br.form

response3 = br.back()  # back to cheese shop (same data as response1)
# the history mechanism returns cached response objects
# we can still use the response, even though it was .close()d
response3.get_data()  # like .seek(0) followed by .read()
response4 = br.reload()  # fetches from server
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually problem was that i was not sending enough information in the header. So i switched to "requests". I divided this request in two phase-

- First to get cookie from server
- second to get the data including the cookie received in first request

Then server responded with proper desired data.